# Simply difficult task from beginner

Tags: loops, button, click, var, classname

I tried to click a button when "ariaChecked" from "checkbox" class is "true".

It's my first project and I don't know what is wrong.

This is my logic

```
setInterval(function() {

     var xyz = document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox");

     if(xyz[0].ariaChecked == "true")
     {
         clearInterval(interval);
         $('.button')[0].click();
     }
},1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need the `[0]` index, because jQuery selected a single element with `$('.button')`. Vanilla JS returns an array, but since you are using jQuery, remove the `[0]` index like this:

```js
$('.button').click();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button class="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click</button>
</body>
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    alert('hello');
  }
</script>
</html>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5oP9.png